# How to check if JQuery is running in another window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script that need to do many things when user is online.

**script.js:**

```
function myFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(online, 10000);
}

function online() {
        $.ajax({
        url: "/php/online.php",
        type: 'post'
        });
    });
}
```

This PHP do many works that I just need to do once per 10 seconds. The problem is, if user opens many browser tabs or windows, this script will run many times. I just want it to run once in one window, but always run this.
any ideas? If possible, simple ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a request is made, you might set an item to `localStorage` corresponding to the current timestamp, and check that the difference between the `localStorage` item and now is at least 10 seconds before sending the request:

```
function myFunction() {
  myVar = setInterval(online, 10000);
}

function online() {
  const now = Date.now();
  if (localStorage.lastPing && now - Number(localStorage.lastPing) < 10000) return;
  localStorage.lastPing = now;
  $.ajax({
    url: "/php/online.php",
    type: 'post'
  });
}
```

Comment: it is amazing, thanks! I tested it using the console and in just one tab the online is called each 10 seconds.